# Filter nested dictionaries to second time key name appears, python

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I would like to filter custom_fields1 so that the only remaining items are the ones who have 'Value' = 'Ja' below the line 'Name' = 'GPP' (and not below the first 'Name' key 'Name': 'Informationen'). Does anyone know how to efficiently filter through the dictionary? I am happy for every tip!

````
custom_fields1 = 
[(44,
  {'@odata.context': 'http://api.hellohq.io/v1/$metadata#CustomFields',
   'value': [{'Name': 'Informationen',
     'Value': '',
     'Type': 'TextMultiline',
     'Id': 18020,
     'CreatedBy': 0,
     'UpdatedBy': 0,
     'CreatedOn': None,
     'UpdatedOn': None},
    {'Name': 'GPP',
     'Value': 'Ja',
     'Type': 'DropdownCheckbox',
     'Id': 18049,
     'CreatedBy': 0,
     'UpdatedBy': 0,
     'CreatedOn': None,
     'UpdatedOn': None}]}),
 (45,
  {'@odata.context': 'http://api.hellohq.io/v1/$metadata#CustomFields',
   'value': [{'Name': 'Informationen',
     'Value': '',
     'Type': 'TextMultiline',
     'Id': 18020,
     'CreatedBy': 0,
     'UpdatedBy': 0,
     'CreatedOn': None,
     'UpdatedOn': None},
    {'Name': 'GPP',
     'Value': 'Ja',
     'Type': 'DropdownCheckbox',
     'Id': 18049,
     'CreatedBy': 0,
     'UpdatedBy': 0,
     'CreatedOn': None,
     'UpdatedOn': None}]}),
 (46,
  {'@odata.context': 'http://api.hellohq.io/v1/$metadata#CustomFields',
   'value': [{'Name': 'Informationen',
     'Value': '',
     'Type': 'TextMultiline',
     'Id': 18020,
     'CreatedBy': 0,
     'UpdatedBy': 0,
     'CreatedOn': None,
     'UpdatedOn': None},
    {'Name': 'GPP',
     'Value': 'Nein',
     'Type': 'DropdownCheckbox',
     'Id': 18049,
     'CreatedBy': 0,
     'UpdatedBy': 0,
     'CreatedOn': None,
     'UpdatedOn': None}]}))]
```
````

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to keep if the value is JA and the name is GPP. Do you want to keep the whole dictionary entry if you find one item of the list matching the requirement? Do you want to filter the list of dictionaries named "values", and keep only the list items matching the requirements... ?

Comment: I want to keep the whole dictionary entry!

Comment: @Theresa_S As you asked for tips, I didn't give you ready to go solution, let me know if everything is clear or do you need more help!

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is sooo nested! Let's break it step by step.

- It's a list, so we want to iterate over it

```
for field in custom_field:
    <I have an element>
```

- What the element is? Its a tuple and second element is what interest me `dict1 = field[1]`
- Now I have a dictionary, where value is what interest me most `values1 = dict['value']`
- Oh, is it list again? Let's iterate again!

```
for dict_value in values1:
    <this is the dict I need!>
```

- I got proper dict, now I just need to check my conditions

```
def check(dict_value):
    return dict_value["name"] == ... and dict_value["Value"] == ...
```

How to do filtering based on that? You can use list filtering

```
[dict_value for dict_value in values1 if check(dict_value)]
```

And assign it to "value" key of outer dict.

Other option could be deleting records with `del` that does not satisfy our check.

Comment: Thank you @kosciej16 for trying to guide me to a solution. I am not sure if I understand how to combine the tips you gave me into a function that provides me with the solution!